# Sort headings alphabetically using regex

Tags: regex, vim, ex

I have a markdown page where the header syntax is `!!!`. For example:

```
!!! Better Heading
This section has a sub-heading
!! Sub-Heading one

!!! Can't think of another one
umm...


!!! A Great Heading
Some text here
```

I would like to sort the blocks of text alphabetically, starting at the `!!!` and finishing before the next `!!!`

Is there a way for me to do so?

Comment: See also http://superuser.com/questions/752032/how-do-i-sort-multiple-blocks-of-text-by-the-first-line-in-each-block-in-vim for a solution inside Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
perl -ne 's/^(?!!!!)/###/g; print;' file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n###/###/g' | sort | sed 's/###/\n/g'
```

first mark all non-header lines :

```
perl -ne 's/^(?!!!!)/###/g; print;' file

!!! Better Heading
###This section has a sub-heading
###!! Sub-Heading one
###
!!! Can't think of another one
###umm...
###
###
!!! A Great Heading
###Some text here
```

then remove `\n` befor these lines:

```
perl -ne 's/^(?!!!!)/###/g; print;' file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n###/###/g' 

!!! Better Heading###This section has a sub-heading###!! Sub-Heading one###
!!! Can't think of another one###umm...######
!!! A Great Heading###Some text here
```

then sort and replace marker with `\n` :

```
perl -ne 's/^(?!!!!)/###/g; print;' file | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n###/###/g' | sort | sed 's/###/\n/g'

!!! A Great Heading
Some text here
!!! Better Heading
This section has a sub-heading
!! Sub-Heading one

!!! Can't think of another one
umm...
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to adjust your regex to get it working within vim but the idea is the same. Here's what I ended up doing as a macro `:%s/^\(!!!\)\@!/###/g<cr>:%s/\n###/###/g<cr>:sort<cr>:%s/###/\r/g<cr>`